# angular 1.2, declaring controllers as a method of module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following dom

```
 <section ng-controller="AppCtrl">
   <p ng-show="currentAirport">Current airport is : {{currentAirport}}</p>
 </section>
```

I used to declare controllers like this without problem

```
 function AppCtrl ($scope) {
   $scope.currentAirport = 'JFK';
 }
```

but recently I tried adapting the same controller code to look like this as per angular docs

```
 var allcontrollers = angular.module('allcontrollers', []);
 allcontrollers.controller(
    'AppCtrl', 
    [
       '$scope',
       function($scope) {           
          $scope.currentAirport = 'JFK';
       }
    ]
 );
```

but … its not working. I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PrimeLens/4wym8/ , could you show me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare main application module using [`ngApp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive:

```
<body ng-app="allcontrollers">
```

Update demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wym8/1/